# For two dependent Poisson random variables, can we compute $\mathbb{P}[\{X_1 = i\}\, \cap \, \{X_2 \geq 1\}]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two discrete random variables (both $X_1$ and $X_2$ Poisson law and not necessarily independent) defined over a probability space, denoted by $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb {P})$.

We know that we can write that :

$$ \mathbb{E}[X_1\;|\, X_2 \geq 1 ] = \frac{1}{\mathbb{P}[X_2 \geq 1]} \sum_{i=0}^\infty \, i\,\mathbb{P}[\{X_1 = i\}\, \cap \, \{X_2 \geq 1\} ]$$

We know that when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, we can write that
$$\mathbb{P}[\{X_1  = i\}\, \cap \, \{X_2  \geq 1\}] = \mathbb{P}[\{X_1  = i\}] \times \mathbb{P}[\{X_2  \geq 1\}]$$

**Is there a more explicit way of writing the quantity $$\mathbb{P}[\{X_1  = i\}\, \cap \, \{X_2  \geq 1\}]. $$**
I tried the following computations:
$$\mathbb{P}[\{X_1  = i\}\, \cap \, \{X_2  \geq 1\}]= \mathbb{P}[\{X_1  = i\}\ \cap \bigcup_{k\geq 1}\{X_2  = k\}]= \mathbb{P}[\bigcup_{k\geq 1}\left(\{X_1  = i\}\ \cap \{X_2  = k\}\right)],$$
which is not very informative.

Comment: $\Pr(X_1 = i) = \Pr(\{X_1 = i\} \cap \{X_2 \geq 1\}) + \Pr(\{X_1 = i\} \cap \{X_2 = 0\})$. Does that help?

Comment: Unless you know the distribution of the random vector $(X_1, X_2),$ there is no way you can calculate joint probabilities.